# Convert MS word form with macros to PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, ms-word, converters

I have created a form in MS word and have few macros running behind, which are required for purpose.
I want to convert this .doc file to fillable Pdf including macros functionality. Is it possible?
The macro is created to check the condition of check box and appear the table, that means if check box is checked it will show the table or if unchecked the table will remain hidden.
Is there any any other way to do this keep the functionality and create a pdf  fillable form?
I really appreciate any inputs.
Thanks

Comment: It's possible but can't be automated. You'd need to reproduce the functionality in Acrobat but then it's not guaranteed to work in all PDF viewers.

Comment: PowerPoint macros use VBA. PDF macros use JavaScript. There is no automatic translation, you'll have to rewrite everything. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf